# Creating a background/daemon thread in JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

I'm using JBoss 5.x (well, actually JBoss 6M1, which is not EJB3.1 compliant).

I want to instantiate a thread running permanently in the background. The thread is going to do some maintenance, and will be started once the maintained resource (a cache) is first used. Although the thread creation will be triggered from an EJB session, the background job shall then run independently of any session.

I want to use a [`javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/resource/spi/work/WorkManager.html) to do that, but I'm wondering how to obtain the (or the best) WorkManager instance to do that.

(1) Do I have to do a JNDI look-up? If so, what do I look for? I found some examples around the net, but I'm unsure why they are written as they are.

(2) Can I use injection to obtain a WorkManager? If anything, it appears to work with @Resource, but takes some arguments to the annotation? Which ones and why?

(3) Would I want to obtain the WorkManager from the BootstrapContext? If so, how can I obtain the BootstrapContext?

Note that I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219149/background-threads), but the options in there don't really work for me (no WAR, no WebSphere, no JavaEE6).

Pointers to relevant specs (or sections thereof) instead of complete answers are also welcome.

Comment: What is your *WorkManager*, could you link the Javadoc. What is the background thread supposed to do?

Comment: Clarified that I'm talking about javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager. Also clarified somewhat what the thread is supposed to do (cache maintenance, hence the thread shall be independent of any (EJB) session).

Comment: Have you considered an MDB? This decouples "submit" and "execution" as well.

Comment: Yes, I have considered an MDB. However, the Work concept appears much simpler to program, and I'm going to need it for another use case, so I'd really love to understand it ;-)